# How to slide up / slide down an element with Zepto on mobile devices?

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, css-transitions, zepto

A common mobile UI pattern is slide up / slide down, for example sliding up an action sheet, then sliding it back down below the screen when it's not in view.

I've tried various css 3 transitions and Zepto's animate function but have yet to find something that works smoothly and consistently on Android and iPhone.

I figure this post can serve as a definitive question and answer:

## **How do you make a smooth slide up / slide down work on Android and iPhone browsers (and by extension PhoneGap)?**

This is a start:

```
#action-sheet {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 200px; /* note that the height changes depending
                   on # of action divs added to the action picker,
                   dynamically from Javascript */
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -50%; /* something that will get it off the screen */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -125px;
  /* maybe some css3 transition here? */
}
#action-sheet.active {
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS and Android browser uses webkit rendering engine, where 3d transforms are hardware accelerated, so that's what you want to use. You should use translate3d.

Adding active class to #action-sheet will slide it down 200px during 2 seconds

```
#action-sheet {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
}
#action-sheet.active {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,200px,0);
}
```